# How do I keep a consistent instance of a GDI+ canvas (TGPGraphics)?

Tags: delphi, canvas, gdi+

I'm making use of a GDI+ canvas in Delphi 10.1 Berlin, using the built-in units `GDIPAPI` and `GDIPOBJ`. I have a thread which is performing drawing, and while looking for ways to improve the performance of the thread, one major drawback is the fact that I'm currently forced to instantiate an instance of this canvas (`TGPGraphics`), perform the drawing, and destroy the canvas, all together at the same time, at the moment I wish to draw. Instead, I would like to maintain a single constant instance of `TGPGraphics`.

## Problem

The problem is that when I attempt to create a single global instance of `TGPGraphics` and use it in the future, for some reason it ends up drawing nothing onto the canvas. It results in just an empty unpainted canvas. It only works when I create/destroy the canvas at the exact moment I need to actually draw anything. I seem to be forced to create the instance, perform the painting, then destroy it, before I'm allowed to read that bitmap image.

The same problem happens elsewhere, not just inside the thread and not just on a `TBitmap`. I faced this issue in the past, but I was able to get away with constantly creating/freeing it for that project. This one though, it's not acceptable.

## Question

How can I retain a single instance of `TGPGraphics` instead of creating/destroying it each time I need to draw?

## Example

Here's a minimal test application which demonstrates the issue. Turn the `GLOBAL_CANVAS` conditional on and off - be sure to do a `Build` when changing, don't immediately go to `Run`. It's just a blank form with no components, just code:

```
unit uMain;

interface

{$DEFINE GLOBAL_CANVAS}
{$DEFINE FLUSH_SYNC}
{ $DEFINE FLUSH_BEFORE}

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  GDIPAPI, GDIPOBJ;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormResize(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FCan: TGPGraphics;
    FPen: TGPPen;
    FBmp: TBitmap;
    function CreateCanvas: TGPGraphics;
    procedure DoFlush;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FBmp:= TBitmap.Create;
  FBmp.Width:= ClientWidth;
  FBmp.Height:= ClientHeight;
  {$IFDEF GLOBAL_CANVAS}
  FCan:= CreateCanvas;
  {$ENDIF}
  FPen:= TGPPen.Create(MakeColor(255, 0, 0));
  FPen.SetWidth(4.0);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FPen.Free;
  {$IFDEF GLOBAL_CANVAS}
  FCan.Free;
  {$ENDIF}
  FBmp.Free;
end;

function TForm1.CreateCanvas: TGPGraphics;
begin
  Result:= TGPGraphics.Create(FBmp.Canvas.Handle);
  Result.SetInterpolationMode(InterpolationMode.InterpolationModeHighQuality);
  Result.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingMode.SmoothingModeHighQuality);
  Result.SetCompositingQuality(CompositingQuality.CompositingQualityHighQuality);
end;

procedure TForm1.DoFlush;
begin
  {$IFDEF FLUSH_SYNC}
  FCan.Flush(FlushIntention.FlushIntentionSync);
  {$ELSE}
  FCan.Flush(FlushIntention.FlushIntentionFlush);
  {$ENDIF}
end;

procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  {$IFNDEF GLOBAL_CANVAS}
  FCan:= CreateCanvas;
  try
  {$ENDIF}

    {$IFDEF FLUSH_BEFORE}
    DoFlush;
    {$ENDIF}

    FCan.DrawEllipse(FPen, 5, 5, 50, 50);

    {$IFNDEF FLUSH_BEFORE}
    DoFlush;
    {$ENDIF}

  {$IFNDEF GLOBAL_CANVAS}
  finally
    FCan.Free;
  end;
  {$ENDIF}

  Caption:= 'Handle: ' + IntToStr(FBmp.Canvas.Handle);

  Canvas.Draw(0, 0, FBmp);

end;

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FBmp.Width:= ClientWidth;
  FBmp.Height:= ClientHeight;
end;

end.
```

[image]

The left is when I create/free the canvas at the time of painting, and the right is when I create/free the canvas at startup/shutdown.

## EDIT

I just noticed something - when `GLOBAL_CANVAS` is enabled in the test above, and then you resize the form to complete minimal size, then make it bigger again, you can see little bits and pieces of the drawing, but not the entire thing.

## EDIT 2

I tried the recommendation to use `Flush`, and I switched it from `FlushIntentionFlush` to `FlushIntentionSync`, and now I have about a 50/50 success rate. Sometimes I run the app and it shows, and other times, making no changes at all, I run the app and nothing draws. I tried many different combinations of using `Flush`, using both methods, before drawing and after drawing. The few times it *does* appear to work, I resize the form to hide it, and make it larger again, and I can only see a glitchy image...

[image]

## EDIT 3

I discovered the *cause* of the problem: the canvas handle keeps getting recreated, so each time I go to draw, the canvas has a whole new handle. I get the same behavior with both `TForm.Canvas.Handle` and `TBitmap.Canvas.Handle`. I'm not sure what the appropriate solution is though. I can't find a way to pass the new handle into the canvas object. The reason why it *sometimes* draws a glitchy image is because sometimes it obtains the same handle, but most of the time, it's different.

Comment: Can't we have a MCVE.

Comment: 1. Do you observe the same if you move code out of thread. 2. Do you flush  TGPGraphics, 3. TGPGraphics is depends on bitmap handle being the same one. And, yes - MCVE.

Comment: I need to stop posting when I'm drunk, I wrote one and didn't include it...

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar 1) Yes, see addition, 2) Don't know what that means, 3) It is, bitmap stays the same.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535692(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Is the value of `Canvas.Handle` different between `TForm1.FormCreate` (where it is presumably created in response to the reference to it) and `FormPaint`? IOW, does the canvas perhaps get re-created?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Oh snap, the handle appears to keep changing constantly - each time `Paint` is called has a different HDC... :-/ But my original tests were on a `TBitmap`, surely a `TBitmap.Canvas.Handle` doesn't behave the same way... or does it? **EDIT** Just tested, yes, it does... So this is my problem, what's the solution?